# Splitting express app.get in multiple files

Tags: node.js, express, file, split

Is there any way to split it without needing to state each app.get?

Like this, I have to add a new app.get for each route.

```js
app.get('/', require('./modules/menu'))
```

The goal is to make it automatic, so it'll get the path, parameters and stuff and send to the correct file.

Thanks!

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly wdym?

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what you're trying to do or what you're asking for help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all URL handler functions to separate files, for example, put all those handlers to files in directory `./modules`.

Example handler file:

```js
function handle(req,res){
    res.send("file1");
}

module.exports = handle;
```

Use a `for` loop to create routes for app:

```js
const glob = require("glob");
const glob_promise = require("glob-promise");

var log = console.log;
var files = [];

async function main(){
    files = await glob_promise("./modules/**/*.js");
    log(files);

    for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++){
        let file = files[i];
        let url_path = file.replace("./modules","").replace(".js","");
        log(url_path);

        app.get(url_path, require(file))
    }
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I work with express

```
app/
   routes/
   controllers
   app.js
```

you can use app.js to import the files for controllers and routes

```
const routes1 = require("./routes/route1.json")
const routes2 = require("./routes/route2.json")
```

inside routes/route1.json you can then import your controllers for those routes:

```
let express = require('express')

const authTokenController = require("../controllers/auth/token")

let api = express.Router()

api.post('/my-controller', myController.myMethod)

module.exports = api
```

The good part is that you can use objects as controllers

```
    class myController {
    
        myMethod(request, response) {
        }
    
    }

module.exports = new authTokenController
```

So now you can load your very well organized app into express

```
app.use('/api', routes1)
app.use('/app', routes2)
```